# Logic behind inbuilt function argrelextrema Python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

There is this function `argrelextrema` in `scipy.signal` which finds local extrema in an array.
This is what I tried :

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

z = np.array([[56,32,12,10,13],[33,55,77,32,11],[12,66,89,43,33]])

argrelextrema(z, np.greater)
```

Output :

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

Aren't the elements `z[1][2]` and `z[2][2]` clearly local extrema? Then why don't they appear in the output?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[argrelextrema](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) takes an `axis` arg, that default to `0`, which can be counter-intuitive. So on your main example, they are indeed no local maximum in this case. On your second example in answer to @tamasgal, 12 < 98 > 89, so there is indeed a local maximum, at row 1, column 2 as stated by the output.

If you set `axis=1` in your call, this would return the correct result:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

z = np.array([[56,32,12,10,13],[33,55,77,32,11],[12,66,89,43,33]])

argrelextrema(z, np.greater, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
(array([1, 2]), array([2, 2]))
```

Note that there is also the [argrelmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html) alias if you want to use `np.greater` as operator.

Answer (score 0):

`argrelextrema` only works on one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: But the following gives an output :
 z = np.array([[56,32,12,10,13],[33,55,98,32,11],[12,66,89,43,33]])  
Output : 
(array([1]), array([2]))
 which is partially correct. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: It seems to be some kind of a side effect due to duck typing. You should look up the sources for `argrelextrema` to find out what's happening under the hood…

Comment: @Sherlocked that is numpy broadcasting i believe